# Not able to insert query into Mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb

I tried to import pymongo and update query into a new database I created - test. For some reason query won't insert into the database.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxx/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["test"]
collection = db["test"]

post = {"_id": 0, "name": "tim", "score": 5}

collection.insert_one(post)
```

The errors that's showing up is the following -

[image]

Do you know what could be causing the error? Nothing is updating in "test" collection.

Comment: Why are you trying to import both `pymongo` as itself and `from pymongo import MongoClient`?

Comment: Ah, okay, the error is simpler: you named your own file `pymongo`. So it's trying to import itself. When you do `from ... import ...`, it reads the whole file to search for the thing you're importing, that's why it's failing on circular import

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have managed to fix your issue but your database might be different I have also added a try statement incase the document already exists.

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxx/<>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["test"]
collection = db["test"]

post = {"_id": "0", "name": "tim", "score": 5}
while True:
    try:
        collection.insert_one(post)
        break
    except:
        collection.update_one({"_id":"0"},{"$set": {"name":"tim", "score":5 }})
        break
```

Comment: That's not the error. When you look closely, the OP just named their own file "pymongo.py", hence circular import

Comment: ah i didn't see the comments